# XPATH: Count occurrences of string with IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am using IMPORTXML in a Google Sheet and would like to count the number of occurrences of a given string throughout the entire XML document, regardless of what container it is in.

I've already found that you can use `count(/Fruit/type[contains(.,'apple')])` to count the occurrence 'apple' in fruit > type. But how do I, for example, count the number of occurrences of 'the' on https://wordpress.org/.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nearest approximation I can think of would be

```
count(//text()[contains(., 'the')])
```

which would give you not the number of occurrences of the word "the", but rather the number of distinct text nodes that contain the substring "the" somewhere within them - multiple mentions in the same text node would only be counted once, i.e.

```
<p>the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</p>
```

would count as 1, whereas

```
<p>the quick brown fox jumped<br/>over the lazy dog</p>
```

would count as 2 since the two mentions of "the" are in different text nodes

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using count(//span()[contains(., 'the')]).

Comment: @Sekoul it would be `//span` rather than `//span()` - without the parentheses as span is an element name rather than a node type.

Comment: My bad - that's indeed what I did.

On the other hand, I'm having a hard time making many of these calls at the same time. They return an NA with "Error: Could not fetch url:". If anyone else is encountering this, there is a thread on it here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/9U4--tlcKq4

Comment: Nice xpath for counting string, plus 1.